# yii php popup Reload

Tags: php, ajax, popup, yii2

i have problem where i can make pop up to view 50 customer, but for pageSize must be only 10.

```
$dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = 10;
```

the problem when click next page the page, i use renderAjax in controller.
javascript

```
$(function() {
   $('.popupModal').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#modal').modal('show').find('.modal-content')
     .load($(this).attr('href'));
   });
});
```

and i use:

```
<?php
      yii\bootstrap\Modal::begin(['id' =>'modal']);
      yii\bootstrap\Modal::end()
?>
```

and i attach my screen shoot for my pop up error

[my pop up page one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x6zC.png)

[error when click next page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bp80s.png)

Comment: Use [Pjax](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html)

Comment: Can u post Gridview and controller code.